# Get json object in Array based on key and value in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a Json body like the example below.  I need to extract the value from a key that has another key with a specific value in an array.  I am passing in a JsonNode with everything in the detail component of the message, I can easily extract from each level, however, I'm struggling with the array.

In this case, I need to extract the value of "value" (Police/Fire/Accident Report) from the object in the array which has a key/value pair of "name":"documentTitle".  I understand this is a JSONArray, but I can't find a good example that shows me how to extract the values for an object in the array that contains a certain key/value pair, I don't think I can rely on getting the object in position [2] in the array as the same objects may not always be present in the additionalMetadata array.

Sample Json:

````
    "sourceVersion": "1.0",
    "eventId": "8d74b892-810a-47c3-882b-6e641fd509eb",
    "clientRequestId": "b84f3a7b-03cc-4848-a1e8-3519106c6fcb",
    "detail": {
        "stack": "corona",
        "visibilityIndicator": null,
        "documentUid": "b84f3a7b-03cc-4848-a1e8-3519106c6fcb",
        "additionalMetadata": [
            {
                "name": "lastModifiedDate",
                "value": "2021-05-21T04:53:53Z"
            },
            {
                "name": "documentName",
                "value": "Police/Fire Report, 23850413, 2021-05-20 14:51:23"
            },
            {
                "name": "documentTitle",
                "value": "Police/Fire/Accident Report"
            },
            {
                "name": "documentAuthor",
                "value": "System Generated"
            },
            {
                "name": "lastModifiedBy",
                "value": "System Updated"
            },
            {
                "name": "createdBy",
                "value": "System Generated"
            },
            {
                "name": "documentDescription",
                "value": "Police/Fire Report received"
            },
            {
                "name": "organizationCode",
                "value": "Claims"
            }
        ]
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the json array and extract the json object with name documentTitile. From that json object you can get the value

Answer (score 0):

Well, either the JSON framework you're using supports this out of the box (check the documentation) or you could convert it manually to a map:

```
List<AdditionalMetadataEntry> additionalMetadata;
[...]
Map<String, String> additionalMetadataMap = additionalMetadata.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(AdditionalMetadataEntry::getName, AdditionalMetadataEntry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I created a new node off the existing notificationBody JsonNode, then parsed through the metadata key/value pairs:

```
    String docTitle = "";

    JsonNode additionalMetadata = notificationBody.get("detail").get("additionalMetadata");
    for (JsonNode node: additionalMetadata) {
      String name = node.get("name").asText();
      String value = node.get("value").asText();
      if(name.equals("documentTitle")){
        docTitle = value;
      }
    }
```